# I cant seem to convert the matlab to code to python. I am getting wrong results. There is something wrong with my for loops

Tags: python, matlab, indexing, fluid-dynamics

Matlab

```
clear all
close all
clc
n=30;
epsi=1e-6;
nn=[0   5    10   20   30   40   60   100  500];
oo=[1.7 1.78 1.86 1.92 1.95 1.96 1.97 1.98 1.99]; 
omega=interp1(nn,oo,n);               % Interpolating a reasonable value
Re=100;
tmax=10;
dt=0.01;
itmax=300;
h=1/n;
beta=omega*h^2/(4*dt);
u=zeros(n+2,n+2);v=u;p=u;

if dt>min([h,Re*h^2/4,2/Re])
    disp(['Warning! dt should be less than ',num2str(min([h,Re*h^2/4,2/Re]))])
    pause
end

for t=0:dt:tmax                % Main loop
    for i=2:n+1                % CalVel, calculation of velocities
        for j=2:n+1
            fux=((u(i,j)+u(i+1,j))^2-(u(i-1,j)+u(i,j))^2)*0.25/h;
            fuy=((v(i,j)+v(i+1,j))*(u(i,j)+u(i,j+1))-(v(i,j-1)+v(i+1,j-1))*(u(i,j-1)+u(i,j)))*0.25/h;
            fvx=((u(i,j)+u(i,j+1))*(v(i,j)+v(i+1,j))-(u(i-1,j)+u(i-1,j+1))*(v(i-1,j)+v(i,j)))*0.25/h;
            fvy=((v(i,j)+v(i,j+1))^2-(v(i,j-1)+v(i,j))^2)*0.25/h;
            visu=(u(i+1,j)+u(i-1,j)+u(i,j+1)+u(i,j-1)-4.0*u(i,j))/(Re*h^2);
            visv=(v(i+1,j)+v(i-1,j)+v(i,j+1)+v(i,j-1)-4.0*v(i,j))/(Re*h^2);
            u(i,j)=u(i,j)+dt*((p(i,j)-p(i+1,j))/h-fux-fuy+visu);
            v(i,j)=v(i,j)+dt*((p(i,j)-p(i,j+1))/h-fvx-fvy+visv);
        end
    end
    for iter=1:itmax           % BcVel, Boundary conditions for the velocities
        for j=1:n+2
            u(1,j)=0.0;
            v(1,j)=-v(2,j);
            u(n+1,j)=0.0;
            v(n+2,j)=-v(n+1,j);
        end
        for i=1:n+2
            v(i,n+1)=0.0;
            v(i,1)=0.0;
            u(i,n+2)=-u(i,n+1)+2.0;
            u(i,1)=-u(i,2);
        end
        iflag=0;               % Piter, Pressure iterations
        for j=2:n+1
            for i=2:n+1
                div=(u(i,j)-u(i-1,j))/h+(v(i,j)-v(i,j-1))/h;
                if (abs(div)>=epsi),iflag=1;end
                delp=-beta*div;
                p(i,j)  =p(i,j)  +delp;
                u(i,j)  =u(i,j)  +delp*dt/h;
                u(i-1,j)=u(i-1,j)-delp*dt/h;
                v(i,j)  =v(i,j)  +delp*dt/h;
                v(i,j-1)=v(i,j-1)-delp*dt/h;
            end
        end
        if(iflag==0)break,end
    end
end

% Graphic display:

U=zeros(n);
V=U;
P=U;
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        U(j,i)=(u(i,j+1)+u(i+1,j+1))/2;
        V(j,i)=(v(i+1,j)+v(i+1,j+1))/2;
        P(j,i)=p(i+1,j+1);
    end
end
figure(1)
quiver(U,V);
axis([0 n+1 0 n+1]);
title(['Velcity vectors, Re =',num2str(Re)])
figure(2)
contourf(P,30)
title('Pressure')
grid on

figure(3)
psi=zeros(n+1);
for i=2:n+1
    psi(i,1)=psi(i-1,1)-v(i,1)*h;
end
for i=1:n+1
    for j=2:n+1
        psi(i,j)=psi(i,j-1)+u(i,j)*h;
    end
end
psi=-psi';
[C,H]=contour(psi);
clabel(C)
title(['Streamfunction \psi_{max}=',num2str(max(max(abs(psi))))])
```

Python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 30
epsi = 1e-6
nn = [0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 100, 500]
oo = [1.7, 1.78, 1.86, 1.92, 1.95, 1.96, 1.97, 1.98, 1.99]
omega = np.interp(n, nn, oo)  # Interpolating a reasonable value
Re = 100
tmax = 10
dt = 0.01
itmax = 300
h = 1/n
beta = omega*h**2/(4*dt)
u = np.zeros((n+2, n+2))
v = np.zeros((n+2, n+2))
p = np.zeros((n+2, n+2))

if dt > min([h, Re*h**2/4, 2/Re]):
    print(f'Warning! dt should be less than {min([h, Re*h**2/4, 2/Re])}')
    
for t in np.arange(0, tmax+dt, dt):  # Main loop
    for i in range(1, n+1):  # CalVel, calculation of velocities
        for j in range(1, n+1):
            fux = ((u[i,j] + u[i+1,j])**2 - (u[i-1,j] + u[i,j])**2)*0.25/h
            fuy = ((v[i,j] + v[i+1,j])*(u[i,j] + u[i,j+1]) - (v[i,j-1] + v[i+1,j-1])*(u[i,j-1] + u[i,j]))*0.25/h
            fvx = ((u[i,j] + u[i,j+1])*(v[i,j] + v[i+1,j]) - (u[i-1,j] + u[i-1,j+1])*(v[i-1,j] + v[i,j]))*0.25/h
            fvy = ((v[i,j] + v[i,j+1])**2 - (v[i,j-1] + v[i,j])**2)*0.25/h
            visu = (u[i+1,j] + u[i-1,j] + u[i,j+1] + u[i,j-1] - 4.0*u[i,j])/(Re*h**2)
            visv = (v[i+1,j] + v[i-1,j] + v[i,j+1] + v[i,j-1] - 4.0*v[i,j])/(Re*h**2)
            u[i,j] = u[i,j] + dt*((p[i,j] - p[i+1,j])/h - fux - fuy + visu)
            v[i,j] = v[i,j] + dt*((p[i,j] - p[i,j+1])/h - fvx - fvy + visv)
            
    for iter in range(1,itmax+1):
        for j in range(n+1):
            u[0,j] = -u[1,j]
            v[0,j] = 0.0
            u[n+1,j] = -u[n,j] + 2.0
            v[n+1,j] = 0.0
        for i in range(n+1):
            v[i,n+1] = -v[i,n]
            v[i,0] = -v[i,1]
            u[i,n+1] = 0.0
            u[i,0] = 0.0
            
        iflag = 0
        for j in np.arange(1,n+1):
            for i in np.arange(1,n+1):
                div = (u[i,j]-u[i-1,j])/h + (v[i,j]-v[i,j-1])/h
                if abs(div) >= epsi:
                    iflag = 1
                delp = -beta * div
                p[i,j] = p[i,j] + delp
                u[i,j] = u[i,j] - delp/h*(u[i,j]-u[i-1,j])
                v[i,j] = v[i,j] - delp/h*(v[i,j]-v[i,j-1])
        if iflag == 0:
            break
    if iter == itmax:
        print(f'Warning! Iteration limit reached at t = {t}')
```

I have tried fixing the indexes. I understand that the MATLAB is a column first (default) in index. And python is row. So in another code snippet I did try changing all the j's with i's and so on. Didnt really solve my problem. I also fixed BC of this code, such that it doesn't show the lid to the right but at the top. I dont understand anymore what is happening. Please help